# List running processes without an image path name using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to use powershell to list only processes on our server that do not have an image path name using powershell. Currently I have (get-process).path but this only returns processes with a path name. Assistance is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for null or blank:

```
Get-Process | ?{[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Path)}
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace checks for blank values, this is good to know.